# Put request entity linked to some others entity symfony

Tags: rest, api, symfony, put

i'm stucked on something: i have to entity `Profile` and `Job`
in the Job entity i have :

```
/**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="label", type="string", length=255)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"profile_details","profile_put"})
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $label;
```

in the Profile entity i have :

```
     * @var Job
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="app.profile.job.not_blank")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Job")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"profile_details","user_details","corporate_details","profile_put"})
     * @Serializer\Type("App\Entity\Job")
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $job;

    /**
     * @return Job
     */
    public function getJob(): Job
    {
        return $this->job;
    }

    /**
     * @param Job $job
     *
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setJob(Job $job): Profile
    {
        $this->job = $job;

        return $this;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
in the controller :

```
public function putAction(Request $request, Profile $profile): Profile
    {
        $profile
                ->setJob($request->get('job'))

        $errors = $this->validator->validate($profile);
        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            throw new UnprocessableEntityHttpException((string) $errors);
        }
        $this->entityManager->persist($profile);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $profile;
    }
```

I'm trying to perform a put on the Profile entity to change some normal `string` fields. I don't know how to set the put request body on postman, i tried to put just the label but i got : `"Argument 1 passed to App\\Entity\\Profile::setJob() must be an instance of App\\Entity\\Job, array given, called in /srv/api/src/Controller/ProfileController.php on line 114"`

Comment: I think the error message can't be clearer than it is. You're passing an array of jobs and not a single one to your `profile` entities `setJobs` method

Comment: @Fabian yes, my problem is how to manage to pass an object ( or if there is another solution to pass the right job) via the put request

Comment: Then edit your question with the code of the controller which handles the put request and an example request you are sending to the controller

Comment: @Fabian it's done

Comment: We need the output of `var_dump($request->get('job'))`, too.

Comment: @Fabien ```"job": {
    "label": "Test job"
  }```

Comment: So there is the problem, this isn't a job entity you have to find it and then set it (`$this->entityManager->getRepository(Job::class)->findOneBy('label' => $request->get('job')['label']`)

Comment: So isn't it better to pass by the job ID?

Comment: Yes, if it is available then use the job id to the find the job entity. But you have to pass an job object to the set method.

Comment: @Fabian thanks i will try like that